# UIBezierPath clip an UIIimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I have a UIBezierPath and I want to get a PNG image from a source image which is shaped like path.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sourceImage.size, NO, 0);
    [bpath addClip];
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But the maskedImage is empty. My path seems to be valid as I tested a fill using the path. Please advice how I can get the part of an image which is shaped liked the UIBezierPath

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, the problem is either your clipping mask or your image. I just tried the below and it worked flawlessly:

```
UIImage *sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example"];
UIBezierPath *bpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height) cornerRadius:50];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sourceImage.size, NO, 0);
[bpath addClip];
[sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The first two lines are mine; the last five are yours. The results looks exactly as I would expect, so either there's a problem loading your image (put a breakpoint when drawing and inspect the results using Quick Look), or your mask isn't what you think it is.

Fun fact: `UIBezierPath` is also compatible with Quick Look, so you should be able to inspect the contents of `bpath` in the debugger to make sure it is what you think it is. Make sure your path is a sensible size given the size of your image!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I wrote my solution [here](http://iosrecipe.blogspot.com/2015/12/drawing-flag-as-overlay-on-top-of.html)

The key was to draw the image as

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
UIBezierPath *bpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
// Add lines to path
[bpath closePath];
[bpath addClip];
[_overlayImage drawInRect:theRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeMultiply alpha:0.4];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```